# ¿Cómo evitar que mi registro se inserte dos veces en MySql desde php?

Tags: php, java, mysql

Estoy haciendo una app en android Studio la cual guarda la información en MySql haciendo uso de un Webservice en php. Al ejecutar el script de guardar los datos (INSERT INTO) me aparece que el registro se guardó pero al revisar la base de datos, éste está duplicado. Este problema surgió al intentar guardar 2 fotos en la base de datos, ya que al principio trabajaba sólo con una y funcionaba correctamente.

Agrego mi código php:

```
<?php

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

        require_once("db.php");

        $id_rb = $_POST['id_rb'];
        $voltaje = $_POST['voltaje'];
        $amperaje = $_POST['amperaje'];
        $velocidad = $_POST['velocidad'];
        $ncordon = $_POST['ncordon'];
        $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
        $turno = $_POST['turno'];
        $hora = $_POST['hora'];
        $motivo = $_POST['motivo'];
        $tecnico = $_POST['tecnico'];
        $nomina = $_POST['nomina'];
        $url_foto = $_POST['url_foto'];
        $horafinal = $_POST['horafinal'];
        $tiempototal = $_POST['tiempototal'];
        $tipoajuste = $_POST['tipoajuste'];
        $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
        $linea = $_POST['linea'];
        $celda = $_POST['celda'];
        $robot = $_POST['robot'];
        $lider = $_POST['lider'];
        $url_fotoparam = $_POST['url_fotop'];
        $defecto = $_POST['defecto'];
        $bloque = $_POST['bloque'];
        
       

        $query2 = "SELECT num FROM robots ORDER BY num ASC";
        $result2 = $mysql->query2($query2);
        

        while($row = $result2->fetch_array()){
            $defaultID = $row['num'];
        }

        $imageURL = "fotos/$defaultID.jpg";
        $imageURLparam = "fotos/p$defaultID.jpg";

        $ServerURL = "http://172.25.12.160/teachingf&p/$imageURL";
        $ServerURLparam = "http://172.25.12.160/teachingf&p/$imageURLparam";
      
       
        if(isset($_POST['id_rb'])){

        $query = "INSERT INTO robots (id_rb, voltaje, amperaje, velocidad, ncordon, fecha, turno, hora, motivo, tecnico, nomina, url_foto, horafinal, tiempototal,tipoajuste, descripcion, linea, celda, robot, 
        lider, url_fotop, defecto, bloque)  VALUES ('$id_rb', '$voltaje', '$amperaje', '$velocidad', '$ncordon', '$fecha', '$turno', '$hora', '$motivo', '$tecnico', '$nomina', '$ServerURL','$horafinal', '$tiempototal', '$tipoajuste', '$descripcion'
        , '$linea', '$celda', '$robot', '$lider', '$ServerURLparam', '$defecto', '$bloque')";

        $result = $mysql->query($query);
        }

        if ($result === TRUE){
            file_put_contents($imageURL,base64_decode($url_foto));
            file_put_contents($imageURLparam,base64_decode($url_fotoparam));
            echo"El ajuste se agregó correctamente";
        }else{
            echo"Error al guardar el ajuste";
        }
        
        $mysql->close();

    }
```

Comment: ¿Que tratas de hacer con ese SELECT y el while de este mismo?

Comment: no me queda claro XD... faltan detalles o una mejor explicacion del codigo...

Comment: @Excorpion con el SELECT estoy tomando el valor de "num" el cual es un campo de autoincremento, este valor es el nombre que le estoy asignando a las fotos que subo ($defaultID)

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent  después de crear las variables con la URL de las fotos (ServerURL y serverURLparam) declaro la sentencia y la ejecuto.  en el if del final hago la decodificación de las imágenes a base 64.

Comment: si traes numeros desde el 1 al 50... cual de todos usas segun tu ??

Comment: @Excorpion las fotos se guardan con el número del registro nuevo. Con tu ejemplo, el 50.

Comment: @ArturoDeJessCamposRodrigue, si el campo es `auto_increment` no necesitas pasarle el número, MySQL lo hace _automáticamente_, solo asigna el valor `NULL` y listo, evitas la consulta y el ciclo. Por otra parte, tu script es vulnerable a ataques, deberías usar [consultas preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Por cierto, en el código que muestras no hay razón aparente para duplicar los registros, probablemente el problema es en la forma de ejecutar el Webservice.

Comment: @Triby estoy casi seguro de que se esta haciendo una doble petición ...

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent, efectivamente, también tengo esa impresión.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me enfocaré en revisar el código de la aplicación.

Answer (score -1):

se me ocurre que puedes crear un unique a la columna que quiere que no tenga valores repetidos

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE (column1, column2, ... column_n);
```

> Fuente: https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/unique.php